# using unique() in laravel, does mysql correctly run onDelete Cascade?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Can I create foreign key pointing to unique combined key?

```
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('unique_id');
        $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();


        $table->unique(['unique_id', 'project_id'], 'parent_unique_id')->unsigned();
```

and then do this:

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('parent_unique_id')->on('todos')->onDelete('cascade');
```

I thought it would work but it fails when I try this.

Does mysql allow foreign keys to point to unique compound field? Or should I do this:

```
$table->index(['unique_id', 'project_id'], 'parent_index');

$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('parent_index')->on('todos')->onDelete('cascade');
```

The reason for foreign key is so that on deleting the parent all rows pointing to it are also deleted.

Problem with just doing:

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('parent_id')->on('todos')->onDelete('cascade');
```

is that parent_id may not be unique per project, so that means delete a parent and all rows will be also deleted even if they belong to another project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('parent_id')->on('todos')->onDelete('cascade');
```

This is an alternative -

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('parent_id')->on('todos')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('no action');
```

Hope this will work for you.